# Nucleophilicity Of Amino Acid Side Chains

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

Out of the side chains of **aspartic acid**, **methionine**, **threonine**, and **tyrosine**, which is the least nucleophilic?

Comment: Highly dependent on solvent, electrophile etc

Answer (score 1):

Aspartic acid < Tyrosine < Threonine < Methionine is the order of nucleophilicity of the amino acid side chains. So, Aspartic acid (neutral form) is the answer. Every side chain has a Oxygen or Sulphur (Methionine) group available for electron pair donation, but in Aspartic acid the Oxygen group has lesser inclination for donation of electron density ([due to resonance](https://chem.libretexts.org/@api/deki/files/12837/3.jpg?revision=1)). Moreover, the solvation layer surrounding the acid group of Aspartic acid makes the job of nucleophilic attachment even more tougher.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: Nope, just arguments. How can one measure nucleophilicity of a side-chain anyway! Nucleophilicity is a property of a molecule or ion.